# jquery .parent .next .show not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="showFilter" /> Ranks
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hideFilter">
    <td class="textBold">

        <select class="ranks singleListBox" id="select1" name="selectListFilterRank">
            <option value="all">All</option>
                <% Do While NOT rsGetRanks.EOF %>
                            <option value="<%= rsGetRanks("RankID") %>"><%= rsGetRanks("Description") %></option>

                <%  
                        rsGetRanks.MoveNext
                    Loop          
                %>                  
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have the following JQuery:

```
$('.showFilter').change(function () {
                if(this.checked) {
                    $(this).parent('tr').next().show();
                } else {
                    $(this).parent('tr').next().hide();
                }

            });
```

I am trying to make it so when they click the checkbox, it will find the parent `<tr>`, go to the next `<tr>` and show that `<tr>`.

That part is not working, it will not show the `<tr>` for some reason.

All hideFilter is doing is setting the display to none, no other CSS should be messing with this currently.

Comment: Was very close on the correct answer, giving it to the guy at the top I suppose.  Dimitri, charlietfl and RobW all supplied a correct way and it is working now.  Thank you all!

Comment: reputation for all :D You'd make a good King :p

Comment: Hey, now that would be a sweet job title. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selects the direct parent, which is a `<td>`.
Use [`.closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select the parent row.

Also, your code can be written even shorter using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$('.showFilter').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using **.parent('tr')**, use **.parents('tr')**

- Parent([query]) only goes up 1 level.
- Parents([query]) searches all parentNodes until it finds what you're searching for.

Answer (score 1):

The parent of your input is a `TD` not `TR` use `parents()` or `closest()`

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

http://api.jquery.com/parents/